# an email can't have more than 1 sender on EmailMessageRelation object

Tags: data-loader, emailmessage

I am trying to import EmailMessage from one org to another.

I am following instructions on this page here

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000380515&type=1

I am on step C1 and  where I am trying to create an EmailMessageRelation record so that I can link it to the EmailMessage record.

Im having issues with the RelationshipType column where I inserted 'FromAddress' as instructed.

I used Dataloader to insert the record.

I get the error '**an email can't have more than 1 sender**'

I am ASSUMING that the FromAddress on the original EmailMessage was trevor.XXX@hello.com is now different to the Users email address which is now trevor.XXX@bye.com.

Is that correct?

This is a screenshot of my csv.

[image]